# How to parse JSON with value to "key" as `dict` object?

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am running into a snag that I think might be an easy solve but I cannot figure it out after a few hours.

I have JSON that looks like this:

```
u'datasets': [{u'kind': u'bigquery#dataset', u'id': u'project-number-1:dataset_number_1', u'datasetReference': {u'projectId': u'project-number-1', u'datasetId': u'dataset_number_1'}}, ...
```

I can access the variables I need with code like this, no problem:

```
datasets = list_datasets_in_project.get('datasets',[])

for dataset in datasets:
    dataset['datasetReference']['datasetId']
```

**But heres the problem**, I have another set of JSON formatted like:

```
u'schema': {u'fields': [{u'type': u'INTEGER', u'name': u'app_id', u'mode': u'NULLABLE'}, {u'type': u'STRING', u'name': u'error', u'mode': u'NULLABLE'}, {u'type': u'STRING', u'name': u'page', u'mode': u'NULLABLE'}, {u'type': u'TIMESTAMP', u'name': u'end_date', u'mode': u'NULLABLE'}, {u'type': u'INTEGER', u'name': u'log_count', u'mode': u'REQUIRED'}]}}
```

and for some reason I cannot use the same logic like:

```
schemas = get_table_schema_result.get('schema',[])

for schema in schemas:
    schema['fields']['type']
```

From what I can tell the difference is that the top JSON looks like:

```
datasets:[{}]
```

and the bottom looks like:

```
schema:{fields:[{}]}
```

I cannot figure out how to get over that next key that is nested. Please let me know if there is more information I can provide. Thank you.

Comment: `schema` is the key for a `dict()` whilst `datasets` is the key to a `list()`, starting from your own get, unless you get `fields` from `schema` your get is trying to pull different type of objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first JSON, `'datasets'` key is holding the list value whereas the one with `'schema'` key is holding the `dict` value. In order to fetch the value you need, you should be iterating it like:

```
schemas = get_table_schema_result.get('schema', {})
#               default value returned as dict  ^
#               if schema key is not present

#      to return empty list if 
#      `fields` key is not present  v
for schema in schemas.get('fields', []):
    schema['type']
```

which will yield result as:

```
u'INTEGER'
u'STRING'
u'STRING'
u'TIMESTAMP'
u'INTEGER'
```

Comment: Damn that was fast and yes it works perfectly. Thank you so much for the quick response. I will accept your answer when it lets me in 5 mins.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options depending on what is the functionality you are trying to implement.

Opption 1:

You iterate array within only one element "field" from your dictionary

```
for field in schemas['fields']:
  field['type']
```

Option 2:

You iterate for each key in schemas dictionary and iterate array within each element

```
for key in schemas:
  field=schemas[key]
```